# Linked Server Intersystem Cache Query Error

Tags: linked-server, intersystems-cache

I setup a linked server to Intersystem Cache. When I run a query against the database I get

```
Cannot get the current row value of column "XXX" from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "CACHE". Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the data type used by the provider.
```

I'm wondering if I'm using the right provider?

SQL Query

```
SELECT * FROM CACHE..tblAccounts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry it is late, the way I get around this is pull the data through an OPENQUERY and cast all values as VARCHAR(350) insert into my staging db then convert back to a suitable data type once in SQL Server.

Usually done using dynamic SQL and the %Dictionary.compiledproperty section of Cache.